# Looking for thoughts on improvement of my javascript (jquery) code. Recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, recursion, jquery-animate

I have made this code that makes some visual "tiles" that fades in and out. 
But at the moment I'm having a little performance problem.

Though most browers are running the code okay (especially firefox), some like safari have problems after a while (a while = like 15 seconds).

I think its due to my recursive function (the function named **changeopacity** that calls itself forever on a delay)? or is it?

But anyways the problem is that this code is really heavy for most browsers. Is there, or more how can I make this code perform any better? any thoughts? (code examples would be nice) thanks :-)

The actual code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var aniduration = 2000;
    var tilesize = 40;

    createtable(tilesize);



    $(".tile").each(function (index, domEle) {
        var randomdelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            changeopacity(aniduration, domEle);
        }, randomdelay);
    });



    $("td").click(function () {
        clickanimation(this, 9);
    });

    $("td").mouseenter(function () {
        var element = $(this).find("div");
        $(element).clearQueue().stop();
        $(element).animate({opacity: "0.6"}, 800);
    });


    $("td").css("width", tilesize + "px").css("height", tilesize + "px");



});

function createtable(tilesize) {
    var winwidth = $(window).width();
    var winheight = $(window).height();
    var horztiles = winwidth / tilesize;
    var verttiles = winheight / tilesize;


for (var y = 0; y < verttiles; y++)
{
    var id = "y" + y;
    $("#tbl").append("<tr id='" + id + "'></tr>");

    for (var x = 0; x < horztiles; x++)
    {
        $("#" + id).append("<td><div class='tile' style='opacity: 0; width: " + tilesize + "px; height: " + tilesize + "px;'></div></td>");
    }
}   
}

function changeopacity(duration, element){
    var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    var randomopacity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    var randomdelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

    if ($(element).css("opacity") < 0.3)
    {
        if (randomnum != 4)
        {
            if ($(element).css("opacity") != 0)
            animation(element, 0, duration, randomdelay);
        }
        else
        {
            animation(element, randomopacity, duration, randomdelay);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        animation(element, randomopacity, duration, randomdelay);
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        return changeopacity(duration, element);
    }, duration + randomdelay);
}

function animation(element, randomopacity, duration, randomdelay){
    $(element).clearQueue().stop().delay(randomdelay).animate({opacity: "0." + randomopacity}, duration);
}


function clickanimation(column, opacitylevel) {
        var element = $(column).find("div");
        $(element).clearQueue().stop();
        $(element).animate({"background-color": "white"}, 200);
        $(element).animate({opacity: "0." + opacitylevel}, 200);
        $(element).delay(200).animate({opacity: "0.0"}, 500);
        //$(element).delay(600).animate({"background-color": "black"}, 500);
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Dude, that's freaking awesome! - Sorry, nothing on the top of my head.  I'll have to check back, that's a really cool effect.

Comment: David thanks - could need help... And Blazemonger I can't delete this post or move it to the codereview page..? anyways sorry if i posted on wrong category... :-(

Comment: Honestly, off the top of my head i think its your animate function. jQuery is inheritly slow. If you could write this yourself I bet you could make it faster.

Comment: Interesting thought ExceptionLimeCat but as i see it, it would be hard to make one my self running as "good" as jquery animate. But anyways interesting thought... :-) More thoughts would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Rather than adding timeouts to every `.tile`, why not store all tiles when you create them, run a Timeout that randomly selects out of you collection and then applies random opacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number one issue is that you are creating one `setTimeout` for every single cell on your page. The only browser capable of handling that is Internet Explorer, and then it fails due to the many CSS changes causing slow redraws.

I would strongly suggest programming your own event scheduler. Something like this, which I used in a university project:

```
var timer = {
    length: 0,
    stack: {},
    timer: null,
    id: 0,
    add: function(f,d) {
        timer.id++;
        timer.stack[timer.id] = {f: f, d: d, r: 0};
        timer.length++;
        if( timer.timer == null) timer.timer = setInterval(timer.run,50);
        return timer.id;
    },
    addInterval: function(f,d) {
        timer.id++;
        timer.stack[timer.id] = {f: f, d: d, r: d};
        timer.length++;
        if( timer.timer == null) timer.timer = setInterval(timer.run,50);
        return timer.id;
    },
    remove: function(id) {
        if( id && timer.stack[id]) {
            delete timer.stack[id];
            timer.length--;
            if( timer.length == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer.timer);
                timer.timer = null;
            }
        }
    },
    run: function() {
        var x;
        for( x in timer.stack) {
            if( !timer.stack.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;
            timer.stack[x].d -= 50;
            if( timer.stack[x].d <= 0) {
                timer.stack[x].f();
                if( timer.stack[x]) {
                    if( timer.stack[x].r == 0)
                        timer.remove(x);
                    else
                        timer.stack[x].d = timer.stack[x].r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, instead of using `setTimeout`, call `timer.add` with the same arguments. Similarly, instead of `setInterval` you can call `timer.addInterval`.

This will allow you to have as many timers as you like, and they will all run off a single `setInterval`, causing much less issues for the browser.

Comment: Don't you think the huge load comes from all those independent delay() and animate() calls?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kolink... Ive tested the code and it seems to improve performance :-) Even Safari browser seems to run it alot better... with no lagging like before when it was running for a while... So super awesome... this made a BIG improvement... May is use this code? or do i have to make one my self? again thanks dude!!! :-)

Comment: note: even putting my var tilesize = 5; only confirms that your code makes a big improvement... it laggs of cause but now the browser can at least handle it, where before it was almost impossible for the browser :-)

Comment: Could you please show us the improved code? I can hardly imagine how to integrate this timer, because you did not use any *intervals* in your original code.

Comment: Bergi - its actually pretty simple. just add the timer code and replace setTimeout with timer.add :-) i didnt really use his timer.addInterval

Comment: Ah, OK, I only read "interval" and didn't realise it could handle single timeouts.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. This is one of my extremely few pieces of open-source code, so feel free to go ahead and use it all you want.

Comment: Oh one more thing kolink.... How do i stop the whole timer? I tried stuff like timer.length = 0; clearInterval(timer.timer); timer.timer = null; but it seems to make it slow if i start it again. I even tried brute force by using timer.length and looping it while using timer.remove(t), but with same result. is there a fancy way to stop it? :-)

Comment: The timer shuts itself down when there are no more timers to run. To stop a timer that hasn't yet run, just use `timer.remove` in the same way you'd use `clearTimeout`.

Comment: ok got it... just added this function     
    clear: function() {
    timer.stack = {};
    timer.length = 0;
    clearInterval(timer.timer);
    timer.timer = null;
    }

that seemed to work :-) thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Nice animation :-) However, I found some bugs and possible improvements:

- Your table is not rebuilt on window resizes. Not sure if bug or feature :-)
- Use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). You have a lot of elements, and every event handler is costly. Sadly, this won't work for the non-bubbling `mouseenter` event.
- It would be nice if you would not use inline styles for with and height - those don't change. For the divs, they are superflouos anyway.
- I can't see a reason for all those elements to have ids. The html-string building might be more concise.
- Cache the elements!!! You are using the `jQuery` constructor on nearly every variable, building a new instance. Just reuse them!
- Your `changeopacity` function looks a bit odd. If the opacity is lower than 0.3, there is 1-in-13-chance to animate to zero? That might be expressed more stringent. You also might cache the opacity to a variable instead of reading it from the dom each time.
- There is no reason to pass the `duration` and other constants as arguments, they do never change and can be used from the global scope.
- Instead of using the timeout, you should use the [complete callback of the `animate` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Timeouts are never accurate, they may even interfere here causing (minor) problems.

```js
var duration = 2000,
    tilesize = 40,
    clickopacity = 0.9;

$(document).ready(function () {

    filltable($("#tbl"), tilesize)
      .on("click", "td", clickanimation);

    $(".tile").each(function() {
        changeopacity($(this));
    });

    $("#tbl div").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).clearQueue()
               .stop()
               .animate({opacity: "0.6"}, 800);
    });
});

function filltable(tbl, tilesize) {
    var win = $(window).width();
    var horztiles = win.width() / tilesize;
    var verttiles = win.height() / tilesize;

    for (var y = 0; y < verttiles; y++) {
        var tr = "<tr>";
        for (var x = 0; x < horztiles; x++)
            tr += "<td style='width:"+tilesize+"px;height:"+tilesize+"px;'><div class='tile' style='opacity:0;'></div></td>");
        tbl.append(tr+"</tr>");
    }
    return tbl;
}

function changeopacity(element) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    var opacity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

    if (element.css("opacity") < 0.3 && random != 4)
        opacity = 0;

    element.clearQueue().stop().delay(delay).animate({
        opacity: "0." + opacity
    }, duration, function() {
        changeopacity(element);
    });
}

function clickanimation() {
    $(this.firstChild)
      .clearQueue()
      .stop()
      .animate({"background-color": "white"}, 200)
      .animate({opacity: "0." + clickopacity}, 200)
      .delay(200).animate({opacity: "0.0"}, 500);
    //.delay(600)
    //.animate({"background-color": "black"}, 500);
}
```

Comment: This is really nice as well... it seems like it makes improvement to use the complete callback of the animate method. all though I'm not sure if its faster than Kolinks suggestion. But interesting way you are writing it on... and many small improvements... thank your very much :-)

Comment: and i like the delegated events... I'm definitely gonna read more into that... :-) Weee

Comment: ... anyways gonna look more into your code tomorrow and optimize my code with many of your suggestions and then compare the timer.add against callback animate method... good nite :-)

Comment: You can still upvote it if you like it :-) I'm  not sure how jQuery handles the animation frames internally, but I guess hooking on that queue also saves cpu load.